# Subnetmask of 255.255.0.0 for servers with static ip?

Tags: networking, subnet

## Short question

Is it a bad idea to give my servers that have a static ip, all a subnetmask of 255.255.0.0, turning it from a Class C to a Class B network? The ip addresses from the servers range from 192.168.10.10 to 192.168.10.20 and are all allowed to see each other. Clients can be in the same range, or in 192.168.11.x

## Long question

I'm playing with my DHCP server setup and decided I want flexibility in my network. I sometimes swap routers with different configurations, and its always a pain to preconfigure my servers to match the router that I'm going to use, especially since sometimes the router is also my modem, where other times its a secondary router.

I've tried in the past to use the DHCP server to give my servers their IP address through DHCP reservations, but I found out this is a pain to setup because you don't know what server has what mac address, and I would need to write these down so I can configure them later on.

I decided that I will use static ip addresses for my servers, which is best practice anyway. Different routers and different modems work under different ip address ranges, and can't always be fully configured to taste. For example, if I have my modem in bridge mode, it will insist to always be at 192.168.100.x range,  which throws havoc to my router network. In the same way, if the modem is not in bridge mode, it will simply not accept 192.168.100.x as range.

I've decided 192.168.10.x is going to be the range where I place my static ip addresses, and every router will, when possible, be configured to have DHCP as 192.168.11.x with a subnetmask of 255.255.254.0. This works great.

My question now is, does it actually hurt, or is it a security risk, if I give my static ip devices a subnetmask of 255.255.0.0 while DHCP hands out a different subnetmask?

In theory the ranges would overlap so the devices would still be able to communicate without any problems, and it would allow me to dynamically grow my DHCP range to a higher size lateron without having to change all fixed ip's subnetmask addresses.

So, is it a good idea to give all my static ip addresses, a subnetmask of 255.255.0.0? If it is a matter of opinion (as in, it doesn't matter), then that is an answer too, which for me means: yes it can be done. If there's a reason why this is a really bad thing to do, then that's the other answer. So its either of the two. If it is a big no, I do expect the reason why so I can learn from it.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I started to write an answer, but although I understand why you are asking about what you want to do, I don’t understand why you want to do it. If the problem here is a limitation of the device, then you’re going to run in to problems anyways. Some routers may not allow a 255.255.254.0 subnet mask. Or other routers may not allow you to choose the 192.168.x.x range. I’m just saying that this isn’t really a long term solution. Why not keep one capable router/L3 switch hooked up to your network and then you can just tweak a setting on that device for anything you plug in in front of it?

Comment: I would say that "the ranges would overlap so the devices would still be able to communicate without any problems" does not necessarily hold. The mask defines if your peer is directly connected or not, if your server has a 192.168.0.0/16 address (i.e. 255.255.0.0 mask) then it will consider all that range local, but if the router has a 192.168.0.1/24, it will try to go to the server (e.g. 192.168.11.4) through its DG. Asymmetrical masks do not always work. Other than that, using a /16 on private space is just fine.

Comment: @Appleoddity I now use a Mikrotik router, so DHCP with custom subnet is not a problem. Then again, I too have a domain controller that I can use for DHCP that can also do a custom subnetmask. I'm asking this to learn from but also to experiment with. If I were to swap out my router for another one, I want to be able to set it up as quickly as I can, so if I run into a problem where I need to tweak my server's static ip addresses for one router, then the point has been defeated. I hope to avoid that by using 255.255.0.0 as subnetmask, and make the other network as close or in the same range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, it's not a security risk.

I think a better solution here would be VLANs for your configuration test network. You need both a 802.1q capable switch and router. This would give you the greatest flexibility. You can also use traditional subnetting if your router actually has multiple interfaces. (Not a consumer grade combo device)

As far as I am aware, there isn't really a right or wrong way to do subnet masks. You usually want to keep it small enough that broadcast traffic won't be a concern (Too many devices in one contingent network space or "broadcast domain"). Other than wasting private address spaces, it's a matter of opinion.

I use pfsense with vlans, it works very well for setting up temporary/home lab networks for configurations. You can then remove the port-vlan membership when you are done, it also allows you to have very tight control over each virtually separated network. (Traffic rules, custom DHCP for each subnet, etc.)

Best Regards,

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. VLAN's is not what I'm looking for. Its my entire network and every device should see every device. My goal here is being able to swap a router with new configuration and be up and running as quickly as possible. I am doing this as a test, but I hope to learn valuable skills/knowledge regardless. :) So far your answer would suggest that the strategy I'm considering would not be of any problem.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "see"? If you mean inter-vlan communication by IP, it would still work. No it wouldn't be a problem. If tight security is a concern on the servers you would want to go either with traditional subnetting via separate physical interfaces & ACL's, or vlanning with ACL's. Absent of strict security requirements you wouldn't need to. These two methods just give you centralized management of all subnets/ traffic.

Comment: I mean, every device should be able to communicate with the other. No VLAN's, just one big network with a few servers and some clients, etc.

Comment: Then you will be fine. As long as all devices are in the same continuous network space / broadcast domain. They will be able to communicate.